# ExtJs Ext.PagingToolbar: hide or set parameters for the refresh button onclick?

Tags: extjs, refresh, hide

No customized setup for the refresh button, so I am trying to hide/remove it.
`hideRefresh: true` didn't work for me.

If there is no way to hide it, can I at least pass some parameters when the button is clicked, so I can make it do some meaningful tasks?

```
pPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    applyTo: 'newProgWin',
    autoScroll:true,
    styleClass: 'formInput',
    bodyStyle: 'overflow-x: hidden',
    align: 'center',
    layout:'fit',
    width:899,
    height:450,
    closeAction:'hide',
    plain: true,
    items: winDataView = new Ext.DataView({
        tpl: resultTpl,
        store: npDs,
       itemSelector: 'div.search-item'
    }),

    tbar: [
                'Search: ', ' ',
            (winSearchField = new Ext.ux.form.SearchField({
                store: npDs,
                width:300
            }))
        ],
    bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
                beforeLoad : function()
                {
                    pocProxy.extraParams = {
                        eps: currentProgs,
                        stateful: true,
                        dataCall: dataCallId,
                        orgNameConvention: currentOnc,
                        installation: currentInstallation
                    };
                },   
                store: npDs,
                pageSize: pageSize,
                displayInfo: true,
               //hideRefresh: true,
                displayMsg: 'Organizations {0} - {1} of {2}',
                emptyMsg: "No Organizations available to display"

            })
});
```

Answer (score 7):

There isn't a property for hideRefresh in the Ext.PagingToolbar.

You can access the refresh button via the bbar (the Ext.PagingToolbar instance) object.

`pPanel.bbar.refresh`

You can hide it using the `hide()` function.

`pPanel.bbar.refresh.hide()`

You can also hide it in your `afterrender` event in your Ext.PagingToolbar:

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function() {
        this.refresh.hide();
    }
}
```

You can modify the behavior of the refresh button by overriding the `doRefresh` function in the bbar

`pPanel.bbar.doRefresh`

Regarding your code, it's not a good idea to overriding the `beforeLoad` function you'll be tinkering with the innards unless its intentional. Maybe moving it to the store object instead?

Make sure you check out the documentation and its code as well because that would help you with debugging. ;)

Comment: Hi, CincauHangus.
actually i tried and Hide method, but somehow pPanel.bbar.refresh doesn't return anything.
to hide it with listeners works for me.
thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Glad it helped. Do mark my answer as the solution if it satisfies your question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This code working fine for me:

```
this.bbar = Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
            store: 'Interactions',
            displayInfo: false,
            preprendButtons: false,
           listeners: {
                afterrender : function() {
                    this.child('#refresh').hide();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 listeners:{
    afterrender:function(){
        var a = Ext.query("button[data-qtip=Refresh]"); 
        for(var x=0;x < a.length;x++)
        {
            a[x].style.display="none";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJs 6.2 I had to use this code:

```
var toolbar = this.lookupReference('pagingtoolbar');      
toolbar.on('afterrender', function () {
    this.getComponent('refresh').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJS 6.5.2 at least (classic), you can override the refresh action as follows:

```
bbar: {
    xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
    doRefresh: function () {
        console.log('Overriding refresh action');
        Ext.getStore('myStore').load({
            params: { // add custom params to existing params
                customParam: 'customValue'
            }
        });
        return false; // cancel load
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can give some smaller width to pagination toolbar so that the refresh component gets hidden :P